# Is "in in vitro" acceptable?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

Is it ok to use an "in" before "*in vitro*", or other Latin-derived phrases that start with "in"?

For example, could you say "there's been a lot of advances in *in vitro* fertilization lately"?

Comment: Not only is it acceptable, you can find several [instances](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20in%20vitro%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1990,cd_max:2006&lr=lang_en#q=%22in+in+vitro%22&lr=lang_en&safe=off&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1990,cd_max:2006,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=k_5lUY2gFInlyAHJ2wE&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45107431,d.aWc&fp=3083123a387b06d8&biw=1087&bih=876) of that exact phrase in the scientific literature.

Comment: It's grammatical and OK as you used it ('in vitro as a stand alone adjective), but does sound a little weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

English has compound words that have an space where one might otherwise see a hyphen. Since *in vitro* is a loanword which behaves as a single lexeme, use it as such.

For purposes of euphony and clarity, I'd probably word it "advances within [the field of] *in vitro* fertilization".

Answer (score 1):

It offends no principles of grammar or good usage that I am aware of, but if it discomfits you, try saying instead "in fertilization *in vitro*".

Comment: If I heard someone say "in fertilization *in vitro*", I would suspect they were a non-native speaker. Also, Andrew Grimm, I think you'd want to say, 'There have been a lot of advances in *in vitro* fertlization." (Not has.)

Comment: @JLG I understand why you would want Andrew to say "have been," but consider that the object is "a lot," not "advances," and "a lot" is singular, unless we're using the British mode, in which case _I think_ the plural verb is used with "a lot" as a collective noun. (Not being British, I'm not quite sure of that point.)

Comment: @John M. Landsberg, In this case, what follows "a lot" is not an uncountable noun, so it needs a plural verb. I agree if the sentence were, instead, something like "There has been a lot of talk.", with an uncountable noun following "a lot," then the singular is used.